# rendering to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-forms

I've been trying to get a dynamic nested form working with ajax in rails 3.

Originally I was following this [example project](https://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples/blob/a234fde4419836f277d7e340657f1d8418911d68/app/helpers/projects_helper.rb) and one of the helpers (add_task_link) looks really good, except that I can't seem to render a partial into a variable. I know that in a controller I can render_to_string, but not from a helper. It looks like in previous versions of rails it must have worked by just assigning the render call to a variable, but not any more.

Is there a workaround for this? I'm sure it must still be possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [capture](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) method:

```
<% snippet = capture do %>
  <%= render :partial => 'some partial' %>
<% end %>
```

Later you can use the variable like this:

```
<%= snippet %>
```